# How do I validate draggableviews form elements when table drag and needs to trigger alert on drag

Tags: view, drupal-7

`DraggableViews` makes rows of a view "draggable" which means that they can be rearranged by Drag'n'Drop.

How do I validate draggableviews form elements when the table drags and needs to trigger an alert on drag.

I have been trying to find a way to best do this, but can't seem to get my head wrap around this.

Example, if a child drag to some other parent, needs to trigger alert "you are moving from xyz title to new parent xyz".

And How do i limit the level of Drag'n'Drop.